# Calculate LEA operand

Tags: ida, assembly, decompilation, patch-reversing, x86-64

I have those opcodes on 64 bits:

```
48 8D 35 45 CE FF FF >>> lea rsi, [rip - 0x31bb].
```

How can I get the 0x31bb value from those opcodes and how can I know if I have a `+` sign or a `-` sign beetween operands ( `rip - 0x31bb` or `rip + 0x31bb` ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that value from the last 4 bytes of the opcode.

```
45 CE FF FF
```

You need to reverse the order of bytes and the the value is written as [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Since the highest bit is 1 it will be negative.

```
(0xFFFFCE45) in 2's = -0x31BB
```